# How to get vaules from a http response returned from facebook api call

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

By making a request to facebook for long live access token, i successfully received a response..
i made a request to - 
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=5096586391&client_secret=4201c4b846d3be4a9fe44&fb_exchange_token=CAAHPiCYlSlMByTFMCY4Er1Yzs1HrOzwpdZCU1VVpdKlvkUg6Rab1KUpFZBYfYNvk7lq0rsWzJjdXnUKFqjMiklxGcoRVjlKmb5fRr51N7Hp7Mpm4Fui0LALXp8ZCSPoN1c9mUN15Gm6BW5rmfdkPW9F1mGgxNZB1kI85TMqgTpEcW1ZCOW7ZB9MaYzmorx8g30N9JwZD

and got response -- 
access_token=CAAHPiCYlSlMBVxXSx29aMW6K2E6ol8xISfzoiZAEvJnhiBgPB2BTzCMTZCIlSKaiZCnJny0XP9fLm73DU4EWJDrldEwYzW0ZAcILVm5S7D2wM6y0Nf68tWUMZCrZCdwFIKqilFS9wDXlYebYpQMyfDtCcH2kfHfQZBKMGMIGeEZA26xJeQvp0d1MMlgsVSy&expires=5182755

Now how do i  get values of access_token and expires from the above http response
i am using django and made the request using 'requests' library.
i am not able to convert it in json also

Answer (score 0):

**Use [`response.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.0-0/api/#requests.Response.json) to get the value of `access_token` and `expires`.**

The [builtin-JSON decoder](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) in the `requests` library returns the json-encoded content of a response, if any.

We will call `.json()` on the response received from the Facebook API. This will provide us with a dictionary which contains the json-encoded content of the response. Now we will just perform lookup in the dictionary for the keys `access_token` and `expires`.

You can do something like:

```
import requests

response = requests.<method_name>('https://graph.facebook.com/...') # get the response

json_response = response.json() # Returns the json-encoded content of a response in a dictionary

access_token = json_response['access_token'] # lookup the value of `access_token` in the dictionary
expires = json_response['expires'] # lookup the value of `expires` in the dictionary
```

**EDIT: This will work for API versions>=2.3 (Thanks [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe))**

As per the [Facebook API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog),

> In v2.3 all Graph API responses now serialize empty arrays in valid
>   JSON format.
>
> **[Oauth Access Token] Format** - The response format of
>   https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token returned when you
>   exchange a code for an `access_token` now return **valid JSON instead of
>   being URL encoded**. The new format of this response is `{“access_token”:
>   <TOKEN>, “token_type”:<TYPE>, “expires_in”:<TIME>}`. We made this
>   update to be compliant with section 5.1 of RFC 6749.

**For API versions<2.3:**

The response format for `access_token` will be url-encoded. You will have to parse the encoded url and retrieve the `access_token` from it as [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) mentioned.

Comment: it gives error - 
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 819, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "c:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>>>

Comment: What do you get as output on doing `response.status_code` and `response.text`

Comment: @Rahul, the response he’s getting _is not_ JSON. API versions from v2.3 on will deliver a JSON response for that endpoint, but older ones don’t, but return the data in the same way a URL query string would be formated, i.e. multiple name=value pairs, separated by an ampersand.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for pointing that out. Updated the ans to reflect the same. :)